# TypeError: this.state.employees.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Here, I am using employee in state as an object.

Getting this error of `map is not a function` while trying to render it as a table. Backend api is returning list of `employees`.

```
class Employee extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            employees:[]
        };
    }

        componentDidMount(){
            fetch("http://localhost:8080/employee/getEmployees").then(res=>res.json).then(
                result=>{
                    console.log(result.id)
                    this.setState({employees:result});
                }
            )
        }

    render(){
        return (<div>
            <h2>welcome to employee.</h2>

            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Employee id</th>
                <th>Employee name</th>
                <th>Employee age</th>
                <th>Employee companyid</th>
                <th>Employee stream</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.employees.map(emp=>(

                <tr key={emp.id}>
                    <td>{emp.id}</td>
                    <td>{emp.name}</td>
                    <td>{emp.age}</td>
                    <td>{emp.companyId}</td>
                    <td>{emp.stream}</td>
                </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>)

    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Employee />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: ``` {this.state.employees && this.state.employees.length && this.state.employees.map(emp=>(```

Always add defensive code.

Comment: Are you getting a result from  console.log(result) and is it an array? NB res=>res.json() not res=>res.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a function to the second `then` not result parsed as JSON.

Simply change `res=>res.json` for `res=>res.json()`.

Answer (score 0):

the reason you are facing this issue is:
1. till the time employees get loaded the render function is already called.
2. you are not converting that response in a json object
3. try using toJS from mobx library to convert into json.
4. and then try {this.state.employees && this.state.employees.map(...)}

Answer (score 0):

The `fetch` API performs an asynchronous task and returns a promise. So when your component is initially rendered, the data is not set. To overcome this error, you can conditionally render a `loading` text while the data is being fetched from your server and the state is set.

Additionally, the `fetch` returns a `JSON` promise. We can read and parse the `JSON` using  `json()` method like this `res => res.json()`.

```js
if (this.state.employees.length === 0) {
  return "Loading...";
}

render(){
        return (<div>
            <h2>welcome to employee.</h2>
      /* rest of your code */
}
```

or if you can simply render it like this.

```js
{
  this.state.employees &&
    this.state.employees.map((emp) => (
      <tr key={emp.id}>
        <td>{emp.id}</td>
        <td>{emp.name}</td>
        <td>{emp.age}</td>
        <td>{emp.companyId}</td>
        <td>{emp.stream}</td>
      </tr>
    ));
}
```